# git checkout -f causing all files to be modified

Tags: git, git-checkout

I just started learning git a few days ago and I started by setting up an example repo.

After performing a successful checkout using git checkout -f, when I run "git status" in the local repo, it comes back telling me all files have been modified.

I do not believe this is normal behavior and from my research, maybe it has something to do with line endings? I am running git on Windows 10 if that helps.

Comment: Are you using the `-f` (aka _force_) option intentionally? Why? Do you use remote repos, so the interchange with another system can affect line endings?

Comment: I used `-f` from a guide I had been following. The repo is located on a network drive that I have mapped. i.e. Z:/path/to/repo and i checked out to C:/users/username/Desktop/repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the `git status` before and after anything else and have a look what state your working dir is currently in.

The checkout with the force option is most of the time not what you want. Therefore I have also to ask: Why are you using -f ?

I guess you want to switch branches but have uncommitted work or a conflict.

You CAN switch branches if you have uncommitted work and it won't conflict on the other branch. But most of the time and in the beginning I would recommend the use of the stash.

Read more here: [Git Tools - Stashing](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)

Comment: Thanks. The use of `-f` was from a guide I had followed. My goal here is to use checkout with the intention of pushing my working tree to production. Hope this may clarify some things.

Comment: checkout is for switching branches. If you want to commit work you should do this on a dev branch and then merge it to production.

Comment: Thanks! I read up on this, created a production branch and this solved my problem. I will avoid using checkout unless switching branches.